# How can I use is_authenticated() in django to redirect user to their own page?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in django framework. I would to make my website to redirect users to the personal page if they already logged at the time they request the homepage like many websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your homepage view you can check if the user is logged in and return a HttpResponseRedirect if they are like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def homepage_view(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/some/redirect/url/')

    ...
```

The redirect respose is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect

If the url you are redirecting to has a name in urls.py the you can use the reverse function to do a lookup of the url from the name
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse